# sending parameter through Url.Action to controller in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, charts, refresh, reload

I'm looking for a solution for this for 2 days already and can't find the answer, everything I find doesn't work so I thought somebody here might help.

I have a chart that I've managed to call from View with Url.Action like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DrawPieChart")"/>
```

but I don't know how to pass the value of the parameter(countryName) through Url.Action so I can pass it through controller and finally use it in AnalyzerData.class

Here is the controller: WebTrafficController

```
 public class WebTrafficController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult WebTraffic()
    {
        AnalzyerData analyzerData = new AnalzyerData();
        //main actionResult that shows stuff not important for this question
        return View(analyzerData);
    }

    public ActionResult DrawPieChart(string countryName)
    {
        AnalzyerData analyzerData = new AnalzyerData();
        return PartialView(analyzerData.getChart(countryName));
    }
}
```

Class: AnalyzerData

```
public class AnalzyerData
{

    public Chart chartImg { get; set; }

    public Chart getChart(string countryName)
    {
        cWebTrafficDb checkUserStatsWrapper = new cWebTrafficDb();
        checkUserStatsWrapper.cmd.CommandText = string.Format("select user_browser, count(*) from user_stats where User_country = '{0}' group by user_browser", countryName);
        //checkUserStatsWrapper.cmd.CommandText = string.Format("select user_browser, count(*) from user_stats group by user_browser");
        MySqlDataReader reader = checkUserStatsWrapper.cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<object> result1 = new List<object>();
        List<object> result2 = new List<object>();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result1.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            result2.Add(reader.GetString(1));
        }

        chartImg = new Chart(width: 350, height: 350)
            .AddTitle("Naslov")
            .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            chartType: "Pie",
            xValue: result1,
            yValues: result2)
        .Write();

        return chartImg;

    }
```

View: Webtraffic.cshtml

```html
@model WebTraff.Models.AnalzyerData
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "WebTraffic";
}


    <div class="inline">
        <img src="@Url.Action("DrawPieChart","countryName", new { countryName = "Croatia" })"/>
    </div>
```

P.S. if this isn't possible please tell me how to do this, I've tried a few different methods and I couldn't get it work

Answer (score 0):

There's one thing you can try here.

Replace this :

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DrawPieChart","WebTraffic", new { countryName = "Croatia" })"/>
```

With this :

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DrawPieChart","WebTraffic", new { @countryName = "Croatia" })"/>
```

Or you can also try it like this :

```
@Url.Action("DrawPieChart", "WebTraffic", new { @countryName = "Croatia" })
```

Try putting the `@` symbol before the parameter name and make sure the parameter name remains identical on both sides.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont think that @ is necceseary before countrName

Comment: I actually thought of considering that for once if it helps solve the issue.

Comment: I believe that the problem is that You can't get partial view as image source.

Comment: @MajkeloDev - Not entirely sure about that. What makes you propose that ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was ever resolved but I just came across the same issue. I found out that using your code of:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DrawPieChart","countryName", new { countryName = "Croatia" })"/>
```

passed the browser the following html

```
<img src="/countryName/DrawPieChart?countryName=Croatia">
```

Changing your code by simply dropping the first "countryName" to match the following:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DrawPieChart", new { countryName = "Croatia" })"/>
```

worked for me... Hope this helps!